# DataBoost used for non-partitioned query - Go Cloud Spanner client

Tags: google-cloud-spanner, data-boost

When trying to write a query using Spanner Data Boost I get the following error:
`DataBoost used for non-partitioned query`

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
stmt := spanner.Statement{
    SQL:    query,
    Params: params,
}
iter := client.Single().QueryWithOptions(ctx, stmt, spanner.QueryOptions{
    Priority:         spannerpb.RequestOptions_PRIORITY_LOW,
    DataBoostEnabled: true,
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries using Data Boost must be executed as described in the [Cloud Spanner docs](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reads#read_data_in_parallel) and use `PartitionQueryWithOptions`. My code that works:

```
txn, err := client.BatchReadOnlyTransaction(ctx, spanner.StrongRead())
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer txn.Close()

stmt := spanner.Statement{
    SQL:    query,
    Params: params,
}
partitions, _ := txn.PartitionQueryWithOptions(ctx, 
    stmt, 
    spanner.PartitionOptions{}, 
    spanner.QueryOptions{
        DataBoostEnabled: true
    }
)
for _, p := range partitions {
    iter := txn.Execute(ctx, p)
    defer iter.Stop()
    for {
        row, err := iter.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        fmt.Println(row)
    }
}
```